# Running MAX of values in another column in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

I'm working on having a column whose values are the running MAX of another column.

My main table has three columns and I use the `summarize` function to virtually add another column named as `SUM OF EACH DATETIME` to the summarized table. Now **I want to have the running MAX of the `SUM OF EACH DATETIME` column in the summarized table in another new column as `MAX of Sum` column**. My table and its preferred columns are shown below:

[image]

I'd appreciate it if you kindly guide me how can I have the MAX of Sum column in my summarized table.
I should note that the formula to calculate the SUM OF EACH DATETIME column is:

```
SUMMARIZE(TABLE, TABLE[DateTimeStamp],
 "SUM OF EACH DATETIME", IF(COUNTROWS(TABLE)=calculate(DISTINCTCOUNT(TABLE[Name]), ALLSELECTED()),SUM(TABLE[Value]),BLANK()))
```

Comment: Hi @Parham, your column "sum of each date time" is a physical column? or you created that using DAY (virtuar)?

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani . The column “sum of each datetime” is not a physical column. It is created virtually using the summarize function. I wrote its formula at the end of my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one measure and one column as given below.

**Column**:

```
date_sum_column = 

var current_row_date_time = ('your_table_name'[DateTimeStamp])

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM('your_table_name'[Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('your_table_name'),
        'your_table_name'[DateTimeStamp] = current_row_date_time
    )
)
```

**Measure**:

```
running_max_sum = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[date_sum_column]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[DateTimeStamp] <= MIN(your_table_name[DateTimeStamp])
    )
)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But please be noted that I currently have the SUM OF EACH DATETIME column as a virtual column in my summarized table and I WANT ANOTHER COLUMN BESIDE IT TO CALCULATE THE RUNNING MAX OF THE VALUES IN THE "SUM OF EACH DATETIME" BEFORE THE CURRENT ROW IN THE TABLE.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. Just created make your SUM OF EACH DATETIME physical to achieve the purpose.